# How to create custom uiview that button can be clicked inside uiview?

Tags: ios, uiview, swift3, uibutton

I tried to create clicked scrollview button like this (at bottom):
[image]

this is my code so far:

```
scView = UIScrollView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: view.frame.maxY-110, width: view.bounds.width, height: 110))
    self.view.addSubview(scView)

    scView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
    scView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    for i in 0 ... 10 {
        let myNewView=UIView(frame: CGRect(x: xOffset, y: CGFloat(buttonPadding), width: 200, height: 100))
        myNewView.backgroundColor=UIColor.white
        myNewView.layer.cornerRadius=10
        self.scView.addSubview(myNewView)

        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: xOffset, y: CGFloat(buttonPadding)+5, width: 150, height: 10))
        label.center = CGPoint(x: 160, y: 285)
        label.textAlignment = .left
        label.text = "I'am a title label"
        label.textColor = .black
        myNewView.addSubview(label)

        let ditancelabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: xOffset, y: CGFloat(buttonPadding)+5, width: 50, height: 10))
        ditancelabel.center = CGPoint(x: 160, y: 285)
        ditancelabel.textAlignment = .right
        ditancelabel.text = "0.04 km"
        ditancelabel.textColor = .red
        myNewView.addSubview(ditancelabel)

        let textView = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: xOffset, y: CGFloat(buttonPadding)+15, width: 200.0, height: 40.0))
        self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
        textView.center = self.view.center
        textView.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.justified
        textView.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
        textView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        myNewView.addSubview(textView)

        let button = UIButton()
        button.tag = i
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        button.setTitle("\(i)", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        button.addTarget(self, action:#selector(handleRegister(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.frame = CGRect(x: xOffset, y: CGFloat(buttonPadding), width: 200, height: 100)
        xOffset = xOffset + CGFloat(buttonPadding) + button.frame.size.width
        myNewView.addSubview(button)
    }

    scView.contentSize = CGSize(width: xOffset, height: scView.frame.height)
```

but code result like this:
[image]

The first button can be clicked, but the other cannot be clicked. And 2 UILabels and 1 UITextView did not appear.

the `handleRegister` method is to get sender tag and print it as log to know the button can be clicked or not.

How to repair the code so it can be like the custom UIView in the above image?

I need to transfer label and textview text by button click to another viewcontroller which handle by seque in `handleRegister`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1)** You can't see labels and other control because of your container view size is (200, 100)

```
 let myNewView=UIView(frame: CGRect(x: xOffset, y: CGFloat(buttonPadding), width: 200, height: 100))
```

and you set center of controls.

```
label.center = CGPoint(x: 160, y: 285)

ditancelabel.center = CGPoint(x: 160, y: 285)
```

This center point is not visible within container view. That's why you can't see labels within view. **Just comment these line to set center of labels and you can see those perfectly.**

2) I need to transfer label and textview text by button click to another viewcontroller which handle by seque in handleRegister.

**I hope you have a array in which you stored data to display in your custom view, Just find that object from array based on button tag, and pass that object to another control.**

**3)** The first button can be clicked, but the other cannot be clicked.

**Again problem is same like for labels**. You had set frame of button like this

```
button.frame = CGRect(x: xOffset, y: CGFloat(buttonPadding), width: 200, height: 100)
```

and increase xOffset by this line to create another view

```
xOffset = xOffset + CGFloat(buttonPadding) + button.frame.size.width
```

**xOffset increased each time with the size of button. So if you print xOffset value it actually print like  (assuming initial value of  xOffset = 10, padding = 0)**

```
for i in 0 ... 10 {
print(xOffset)
..... your other code

}
```

**Output:** will be like 
10, 210, 410, 610...... Because of this your button is out of bound from container view and because of that you can't click on that.

**I have updated your code, check below**

```
scView = UIScrollView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: view.frame.maxY-110, width: view.bounds.width, height: 110))
    self.view.addSubview(scView)

    scView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
    scView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    for i in 0 ... 10 {
        let myNewView=UIView(frame: CGRect(x: xOffset, y: CGFloat(buttonPadding), width: 200, height: 100))
        myNewView.backgroundColor=UIColor.white
        myNewView.layer.cornerRadius=10
        self.scView.addSubview(myNewView)

        let subVwOffset = 5

        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: subVwOffset, y: CGFloat(buttonPadding)+5, width: 150, height: 10))
        label.textAlignment = .left
        label.text = "I'am a title label"
        label.textColor = .black
        myNewView.addSubview(label)

        let ditancelabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: subVwOffset, y: CGFloat(buttonPadding)+5, width: 50, height: 10))
        ditancelabel.textAlignment = .right
        ditancelabel.text = "0.04 km"
        ditancelabel.textColor = .red
        myNewView.addSubview(ditancelabel)

        let textView = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: subVwOffset, y: CGFloat(buttonPadding)+15, width: 200.0, height: 40.0))
        self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
        textView.center = self.view.center
        textView.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.justified
        textView.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
        textView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        myNewView.addSubview(textView)

        let button = UIButton()
        button.tag = i
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        button.setTitle("\(i)", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        button.addTarget(self, action:#selector(handleRegister(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.frame = CGRect(x: subVwOffset, y: CGFloat(buttonPadding), width: 200, height: 100)
        xOffset = xOffset + CGFloat(buttonPadding) + button.frame.size.width
        myNewView.addSubview(button)
    }

    scView.contentSize = CGSize(width: xOffset, height: scView.frame.height)
```

Let me know if you find any other difficulty.

Comment: 1. i see the problem .center.

Comment: but how to make all looping button can be clicked?

Comment: @Sarimin  Check my answer, I have updated my answer.